# get form values into objects array + display the objects in dynamic table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm new to all of this php stuff, and since my background is in Java, everything seems to me like a real mess.

EXPLANATION:
I have a form which I need to get user's input and post it into a table in another page.
I think that this table supposed to be a dynamic table, so there will be no limitations of adding multiple objects.
An object is added once at a time, when I finish to fill the form and click on submit.

this is the form where I need to get user's input:

```
<p>Assignment name</p>  
<form action="the_next_page.php" method="post">
<input id="assignment_name" name="asgn_name">

<p>Due Date</p>
<input id="due_date" name="due_date" type="date"><br>

<p>Rank:</p>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="1" checked> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="rank" value="5"> 5<br>

<p>Description</p>
<textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>

<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
<input name="reset" type="button" value="Reset">

</form>
```

as you can see there are different types of values I need to get together, therefore I created a class and a constructor:

```
<?php
$Arr=array();

class assignment {
public $asgn_name;
public $asgn_due_date;
public $asgn_rank;
public $asgn_description;


public function __constructor($asgn_name, $asgn_due_date, $asgn_rank,    
$asgn_description){
$this-> $asgn_name=$asgn_name;
$this-> $asgn_due_date=$asgn_due_date;
$this-> $asgn_rank=$asgn_rank;
$this-> $asgn_description=$asgn_description;
}

}

$assignment_temp=new assignment($asgn_name=$_REQUEST['name'],    
$asgn_due_date=$_REQUEST['due_date'], $asgn_rank=$_REQUEST['rank'], 
$asgn_description=$_REQUEST['comments']);

array_push($Arr, $assignment_temp);
?>
```

*I'm not sure that this part is well written, pardon...*

Now, the point is that I need to get all the objects attributes out of the form page, and pass them to the next page (when clicking the submit) where I should display them on a table.

the table is:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>text field</td>
<td>Date field</td>
<td>Radio button selection</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?php echo ($_SESSION['due_date']=$_REQUEST['asgn_name']);?>   
</td>
<td><?php echo ($_SESSION['due_date']=$_REQUEST['due_date']);?> </td>
<td><?php echo ($_SESSION['due_date']=$_REQUEST['rank']);?> </td>   
</tr>

</table>
```

the $_SESSION / $_REQUEST you see within the table is a temporary solution which helps me only to display the fields, but it won't save the values into the object.
Also, it only displays the last values inserted, and over write the values when I insert new ones.

So, basically my questions are:
1) How can I get the form values into objects array and pass them to the next page?
2) How can I save locally the objects so a new object won't over write the previous one inserted?
3) Is dynamic table the best solution in this case (for a display)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Posting_page.php` is where you take all of the values passed into the form?

Comment: So can users submit multiple assignments on the form page at once?

Comment: This question is too broad. There's not a bit of PHP code here, this is not a code-writing service. Put some effort into solving the problem yourself and you'll get some good help.

Comment: I tried to improve my question. thank you for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**1) How can I get the form values into objects array and pass them to the next page?**

If you have a dynamic array that could have many objects in it, you can get a tidy array in your $_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST data by carefully naming your form inputs. This approach usually works well in PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo '<input name="objs[' . $i . '][val1]" type="text">';
    echo '<input name="objs[' . $i . '][val2]" type="text">';
    echo '<input name="objs[' . $i . '][val3]" type="text">';
}
```

As you can see, we are using brackets to try and denote an array. If your form method="post" then your var_dump($_POST) might look something like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'objs' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'val1' => string 'v1-0'
      'val2' => string 'v2-0'
      'val3' => string 'v3-0'
      1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'val1' => string 'v1-1'
      'val2' => string 'v2-1'
      'val3' => string 'v3-1'
      2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'val1' => string 'v1-2'
      'val2' => string 'v2-2'
      'val3' => string 'v3-2'
      3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'val1' => string 'v1-3'
      'val2' => string 'v2-3'
      'val3' => string 'v3-3'
      4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'val1' => string 'v1-4'
      'val2' => string 'v2-4'
      'val3' => string 'v3-4'
```

**2) How can I save locally the objects so a new object won't over write the previous one inserted?**
Not at all sure what you mean by this. If you are doing a database INSERT every time, then it will always create new records so you don't have to worry about an UPDATE on any previous records. The details here will depend on your db structure.

**3) Is dynamic table the best solution in this case (for a display)?**
That all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.